# Workaround for running privileged commands from www-data user

Tags: permissions, sudo, php, web, account-restrictions

I would like to append a string to a file located in /tmp/ from a php script. The command I would like to execute is:

```
sudo sed -e 's/$/,yes/' -i /tmp/a.csv
```

**The Problem**

I can't run a sudo command from php using `shell_exec()` since I am constrained by the limitations of the non-root account www-data. How can I overcome this limitation?

I am looking for a method to trigger a privileged command from php, do you have any advice?

**EDIT**

The a.csv file is **dynamically** created from another mysql command which exports the result of a query to a csv file. 
I tried, as you suggested, to export the file to /var/www/html/tmp/a.csv but mysql returns

```
Can't create/write to file '/var/www/html/tmp/a.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

The /tmp/ folder is the only one I can save files in without modifying security rules

Comment: how are you calling the php script ? If from a web page, it should be running as www-data, you simply need to set the file(s) to be accessible by www-data. so a.csv should IMHO be owned by www-data and you should not need sudo at all.

Comment: Yes it is called from a web page. I have tried with `sudo chown www-data /tmp/a.csv` but nothing happened when the script was executed. Let me add more information. Please see my edit

Comment: Well, personally, I would not put a.csv in /tmp , put it in /var/www/html/tmp and it should be owned by www-data . a.csv  should have permissions of 600 or 660 .

Comment: Since the file is created from a mysql command, the only folder I can export files in is /tmp/.

Comment: Probably best to post your script as calling sudo from a php script on a web page is insecure or change the permissions of /var/www/html/tmp so mysql can write to it. Your basic problem is with prmissions (as far as I can tell) and you are going to make matters worse calling sudo from your php script.